# Invoke Powershell with cmd and utf8 parameter

Tags: powershell

In a UTF-8 batch, I try to invoke:

```
powershell Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb runAs -Arg '/k chcp 65001 ^& echo été'
```

But the echo was :

```
Page de codes active : 65001
├®t├®

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I would like "été" and not "├®t├®"

Comment: Have you tried the new Windows Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [Console.OutputEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?view=netframework-4.8) to UTF8 like this:

```
powershell.exe -Command {
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Utf8
    Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb runAs -Arg '/k echo été'
}
```

Result:

> été